# How to programmatically update a label based on the section of a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

Say I have a horizontal `UICollectionView` with 3 sections. I want it to immediately update a label based on which section the user is in as they are scrolling. I found a few solutions that do this by using `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`, but I want it to update the moment it goes from section 0 to section 1, from section 1 to section 2, etc.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

there are

```
let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow();
var sectionNumber = indexPath.section
```

and check if 0 show update the first label and so on but i think best place in cell for row at index and get the section number then update it's label

there are another solution

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

            //Create label and autoresize it
            let headerLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.width, 2000))
            headerLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Light", size: 30)
            headerLabel.text = self.tableView(self.tableView, titleForHeaderInSection: section)
            headerLabel.sizeToFit()

            //Adding Label to existing headerView
            let headerView = UIView()
            headerView.addSubview(headerLabel)

            return headerView
}
```

also try this

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) 
{
    let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 11)
    header.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
}
```

Comment: So this isn't about headers. I wanted to make the question simple with a single label, but I actually have about a dozen buttons that have images, that need to change their image if the user is in the correct section. So if you're in section 0, the button goes from "emoji-unselected" to "emoji-selected". In section 1, it goes from "animals-unselected" to "animals-selected", and so forth.

Comment: @VDog it sort of depends on what you mean by the user being "in the correct section." Multiple sections can usually be onscreen at the same time. I'd personally try using `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)` and check the section of the index path, but that's pretty coarse, maybe write some heuristic for analyzing the array of  `collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems` to see how many are of which section.